# Can't connect to a multiuser screen session using * flag

Tags: linux, display, terminal, tmux, multiuser

I am currently trying to set up a multi user screen environment and am having some trouble adding users.

According to screens man page a single * can be used instead of a specific username to allow access for all users, however this doesn't seem to be working.

> Change permissions for a comma separated list of users. Permission bits are represented as ‘r’, ‘w’ and ‘x’. Prefixing ‘+’ grants the permission, ‘-’ removes it. The third parameter is a comma separated list of commands or windows (specified either by number or title). The special list ‘#’ refers to all windows, ‘?’ to all commands. If usernames consists of a single ‘*’, all known users are affected. A command can be executed when the user has the ‘x’ bit for it. The user can type input to a window when he has its ‘w’ bit set and no other user obtains a writelock for this window. Other bits are currently ignored. To withdraw the writelock from another user in e.g. window 2: ‘aclchg username -w+w 2’. To allow read-only access to the session: ‘aclchg username -w "#"’. As soon as a user’s name is known to screen, he can attach to the session and (per default) has full permissions for all command and windows. Execution permission for the acl commands, at and others should also be removed or the user may be able to regain write permission. Chacl is a synonym to aclchg. Multi-user mode only.

Currently creating a session, turning on multiuser, and executing the following screen command seems not to return any type of error or indication that it shouldn't work:

```
multiuser on
aclchg * +rxw "#?"
```

However, when attempting to attach from a different user the standard "Access denied" error persists

When providing a specific username it seems to work as it should though...

Comment: Is it about GNU `screen`? There is no [tag:gnu-screen] among the tags you used, but there is [tag:tmux]. I don't think the question is about `tmux`. Please review the tags.

Comment: What does the `display` command return? The `*` wildcard refers to all _known_ users. Maybe there are no users before you run that command, even though `aclchg username +rxw "#?"` has the same effect of the `acladd` command, but should not work with `*` if there are no users.